# Difficulty unzipping ubuntu using ES File Explorer for Android

Tags: android, unzip

Whenever I try to unzip `ubuntu- 13.04.LARGE.ext4.v2.zip` to `/sdcard/ubuntu` it tells me

```
"exception found!(Bad size: -294967296)."
```

I have googled around but I can't find an answer. Can you please help me understand why this isn't working? It worked for the `ubuntu- 13.04.CORE.ext4.v2.zip` file but it won't for the `ubuntu- 13.04.SMALL.ext4.v2.zip`, with the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ES File Manager cannot decompress large files. Use [ZArchiver](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ru.zdevs.zarchiver) instead.

Answer (score 0):

To exchange files and manage try Solid Explorer. I think that to decompress there are many options, AZIP master or RAR or 7zip, you also have to use some applications, you can enter the zip and extract a specific file. Keep in mind if it is an ISO you may have files left without extracting and also that it is another matter if the application you use recognizes the files. There is also an Android app for ISO images.